# Bash - adding numbers from array matrix

Tags: bash, unix, matrix, sum, addition

When adding numbers in a matrix, I get this error:
**line 271: 1 2 3 4: syntax error in expression (error token is "2 3 4")**

My add function:

```
add()
{
   #Reading matrices into temp files 
   while read line1 <&3 && read line2 <&4
   do
      echo "$line1" | tr "\n" "\t" >> "temp50"
      echo "$line2" | tr "\n" "\t" >> "temp60"
   done 3<$temp1 4<$fileTwo
   echo >>"temp50"
   echo >>"temp60"

cat "temp60" >> "temp50"

i=1
x=1

while [ $i -le $totalNum ]
do
   sum=0
   cut -f $i "temp50" > "temp55"

   while read num
   do
      sum=$(($sum + $num))
   done <"temp55"

   echo "$sum" | tr "\n" "\t" >> "temp65"

   #try and remove hanging tab
   if [[ "$x" -eq "$numcolOne" ]]
   then
      rev "temp65" > "temp222"
      cat "temp222" | cut -c 1- >"temp333"
      rev "temp333">"temp65"
      x=0
   fi

   i=$((i+1))
   x=$((x+1))

done
```

Matrix array (temp1):

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

Function is supposed to add the matrix array in the temp1 file; sample output:

2 4 6 8

10 12 14 16

Appreciate anyone's help!

Comment: Paste that into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and see if there is trouble.

Comment: Wha tis the content of the files named `"$temp1" and `"$fileTwo"`? What what you are trying to do? What is the point of `while read` and then `tr, why not just `tr`? Why do you use `cut`? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What is the input to the function? What are you trying to do?

Comment: My *Guess* is that in `while [ $i -le $totalNum ]`, the variable `totalNum` contains `"1 2 3 4"` and since it is unquoted, you get the error.

Comment: You have a lot of `temp` things in your code, it is difficult to understand. Can you explain what you want to do? The first line (not an array?) of your sample input is `1 2 3 4`, and by adding something the desired result is `2 4 6 8`.  Do you want to double each field or is this what happends wen you try to add `temp1 + temp1`?